# How to close LWC Quick Action when the page is refreshed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-controller

I have a quick Action button on Account page which is calling the LWC lightning-quick-action-panel component. By clicking on the quick Action button a model box opens, now when I refresh the Account page, the opened quick Action is not closing. it stays on the screen.

Does anyone know how to close this Quick Action model box when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Can you share your component code?

Comment: I think CloseActionScreenEvent should resolve your issue.

Comment: CloseActionScreenEvent is used to close the model box when user click the Cancel button. But when user refreshed the browser page after clicking on the quick action button, the opened Quick Action model box is not closed after page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue,
you can prevent the component from being refreshed by using track decorator

```
@track hasRendered = false; // To Prevent Modal from ReRendered once Disconnected
```

in connected Callback

```
    connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, modal)
    ]).then(() => {
        this.getBundles();
    });
}
```

then in your disconnected callback

```
    disconnectedCallback() {
    this.hasRendered = true;
    // location.reload(); // Don't use this. It will revoke your modal-calling Promise because this initialize all properties so track-ed property indicator doesn't work as expected
}
```

Comment: Isn't the [track decorator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields) unnecessary for anything but arrays and objects?